# A object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(bool)'

Tags: c#, android, android-actionbar, xamarin.android

Iam using A ActionBar in my app. I have done something like so:-

```
ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

But I get a compilation error like:-

> A object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property
>   'Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(bool)'

What could be the problem/? Iam developing android in C# for the first time. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: It seems `SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` is instance method, but you're accessing it as it were static. You need to create an instance of `ActionBar` then call `actionBarInstance.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. Refer suggested duplicate for more info.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ActionBar is a abstract class. How do I create its instance

Comment: You need to create an instance of it's sub class, Find it otherwise ask a new that's because that's a new question indeed..

Comment: First of all, your Activity has to be derived from either ActionBarActivity or one of it's sub-classes. Then you'll see the ActionBar property. If you're using AppCompat, then you'll need to use the SupportActionBar property.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ActionBar is the name of a class, as well as a property on the class ActionBarActivity. If OP did not derive from ActionBarActivity, then that property wouldn't exist and the compiler would treat it as if he was accessing a static property of class ActiionBar. That's where the error message is coming from. He does not need to create an instance of ActionBar.